# jQuery call function only when object is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using FitText https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js to resize the text of some text I have in specific DIVs. The fact is that these DIVs are created into objects added to the page only when needed. But doing this way FitText won't get the DIV when page loads because in fact the DIV is not already there and so won't resize the text.

Here is how I call FitText:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery(".cvd_right_master_item").fitText(2.8);
    });
</script>
```

And here is the function that creates the DIV into an object:

```
function makeCvdBubble(params)
    {  
    var cvdIndexId = params.cvdIndexId;
    var cvdTweetAuthor = params.cvdTweetAuthor;
    var cvdAuthorName = params.cvdAuthorName;
    var cvdTweetDescription = params.cvdTweetDescription;

    objectreference = document.createElement('div');
    objectreference.setAttribute('id', 'indexId-'+cvdIndexId.toString());


    $(objectreference).html('\
    <div class="cvd_right_master_item">\
                    <div class="cvd_right_tweet_margin_float">\
                        <img class="cvd_right_blue_bird" src="cross_video_day/images/cvd_blue_bird.png" /><span class="cvd_right_tweet_username">@UserName</span>\
                        <span class="cvd_right_tweet_author">User Name</span>\
                        <span class="cvd_right_tweet_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ut posuere justo, eget consequat tortor. In sollicitudin condimentum arcu sed.</span>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="clear_both"></div>\
                    <span class="cvd_right_white_arrow"></span>\
                </div>\
');

    if (cvdTweetAuthor) $(objectreference).find('.cvd_right_tweet_username').html(cvdTweetAuthor);
    if (cvdAuthorName) $(objectreference).find('.cvd_right_tweet_author').html(cvdTweetAuthor);
    if (cvdTweetDescription) $(objectreference).find('.cvd_right_tweet_text').html(cvdTweetDescription);

    return (objectreference) //objectreference is the reference of the just created tweet
    }
```

Now how do I do to make FitText resizing the text when the object is created?
Thank you!

Comment: unrelated to an answer, but for good practice.. you are using `..function($) {`  don't put the `$` unless you are going to use it. plus, if you are trying to do that, why not just use `$(document)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After appending the object to the DOM.

Try this:

```
   var myObj = $("TheParentDOMObject").appendChild(makeCvdBubble(params));
   myObj.fitText(2.8);
```

Comment: I am not sure I got this solution. Can you explain a bit more based  on my example please?

Comment: How do you call the function makeCvdBubble?